# How do I put a search in the text box in a report view with Microsoft Report builder?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, obiee, reportbuilder

I'm migrating reports from OBIEE to RS with Microsoft Report Builder.

My question is that in OBIEE you can filter in the view
[Como aquí se ve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Prc.png)

In Report builder I can't find any option that does the same, only that I sort by some field, do you know how I can do that OBIEE in Report Builder that you can choose in the already generated view the fields you want?

Thank you for your help.

In interactive sorting, just sort.

Comment: The short answer is "you cannot do this". Other than collapsing/expanding areas, there is not much you can do wit the report rendered on screen without changing parameters and running the report again.